# Link for the Xamarin.Mac 7.2.0.3 (Mac)

Tags: download, visual-studio-mac, xamarin.mac

I need the download link for the Xamarin.Mac version 7.2.0.3.
I mean, the installer for that component on Mac.

If I loose my data, I want to have a safe installation "disk", for my Visual Studio IDE, having the same components that are working right now.

My project is stable with the current features, and I don't want to loose it, if I need to reinstall everything.

Could anybody help?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/370610/visual-studio-for-mac-offline-installer.html

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The link mentioned by Lex Li, gave all information that I needed.